# Is D3.js really data-driven?

Tags: programming-languages

In The Art of Unix Programming, Eric Raymond tells that the data-driven style is about creating small interpreters for "mini-languages" to allow controling the control-flow of the program at runtime.

How is that related to displaying data ? I could not find anything that was about creating DSLs in D3.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The d3.js library *is* an ["embedded DSL"](http://wiki.c2.com/?EmbeddedDomainSpecificLanguage).  It's embedded (using the syntax of the javascript host language), in contrast to a ["freestanding DSL"](http://wiki.c2.com/?FreestandingDomainSpecificLanguage), which corresponds to what Eric Raymond is talking about in "The Art of Unix Programming".

And it's a DSL, because it implies a different programming style.  In d3.js you describe the relationship between your data and the desired visual, instead of creating loops over loops prescribing what to do next.

To [quote from the d3.js page](https://d3js.org/#selections):

> Modifying documents using the W3C DOM API is tedious: the method names are verbose, and the imperative approach requires manual iteration and bookkeeping of temporary state. For example, to change the text color of paragraph elements:
>
> ```
> var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
> for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
>    var paragraph = paragraphs.item(i);
>    paragraph.style.setProperty("color", "white", null);
> }
> ```
>
> D3 employs a declarative approach, operating on arbitrary sets of nodes called selections. For example, you can rewrite the above loop as:
>
> ```
> d3.selectAll("p").style("color", "white");
> ```

See this [example of d3.js in the wild](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5c50a377e76a1974248bd628befdec95).  with procedural javascript you'll create several loops and selects and subselects, instead of describing what to do with which part of the data.

Another fantastic example of an embedded DSL is ["ggplot"](http://ggplot2.org/) from Hadley Wickham, in the R programming language.

Comment: I agree, but I don't understand at all how it is related to the definition of "data-driven" as given by E. Raymond. e.g. a data-driven software is a software where you create your own embedded interpreter; d3 does not seems to be an interpreter for anything.

Comment: There is a more consensual notion of "data-driven" meaning:  you describe how the program/software/system reacts to which kind of data, and the detailed steps to be taken are generated from that description automatically.

Then the input data is processed according to the rules you have given.

This is a super set of what Eric Raymond says.

Comment: so a domain specific language doesn't have to be an interpreter on it's own. it can simply be a library that is smooth to use, and that moves from telling the system how to do things with loops to telling the system what to do `d3.selectAll(...).style.(...)` This **is** a DSL, just in javascript syntax.  hth?

Comment: do you have some kind of paper that presents this definiton formally ?

Comment: A google scholar search for [domain specific language d3](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?q=domain+specific+language+d3&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_vis=1) comes up with a paper [D³ Data-Driven Documents](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6064996/) which was cited by another 130ish publications so far, for your convenience [here is the pdf](https://data3.mprog.nl/course/15%20Readings/60%20Reading%206/Bostock_D3.pdf).

Comment: In this paper the original author of d3.js, Mike Bostock, describes at lengths how d3.js is different from a procedural framework.  The paper was published with Mike simply stating that d3.js actually constitutes a Domain Specific Language.  the paper got published in a reputable IEEE publication, so we can assume it was obvious to the reviewers that this is correct.  If you need scholar definitions for "domain specific language", the google scholar search will for sure give you plenty.  But that's beyond this question here, which was whether d3.js is "data driven".

Comment: okay, it seems that the meaning of "data-driven" really has a different meaning in the computer graphics world than in the PLT one. For instance in the paper Protovis is cited, which offers deferred rendering, i.e. lazyness, which is a cornerstone of "traditional" data-driven programming by opposition to immediate mode.

Comment: with all due respect for Eric, who I had the joy of hearing his Cathedral and Bazaar talk life in the 1997, also long time fetchmail user speaking, he is _not_ the sole and authoritative source for programming language theory.

As you made me curious I digged a little further and I've added the distinction of "embedded DSL" vs "freestanding DSL" above.

does this now answer your original question?

Comment: for the record I've also added trustable references to freestanding and embedded DSLs on the [Mother of All Wikis](http://wiki.c2.com/), which is especially dedicated to [software engineering patterns](http://wiki.c2.com/?WikiPagesAboutWhatArePatterns)